# Pause MyApp during modal.present()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, modalviewcontroller, apache-cordova

### Original Post:

I am coding an Ionic 2 Hybrid app and attempting to create a modal that logs into FB and gathers necessary information for the app to run properly.

While the modal is presented (and the user is logging in), I need the app to be paused in the background. In other words, it cannot be continuing with the subsequent processes until the modal is dismissed.

Here is the relevant portion of code as an example:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  console.log("User is already signed in.");
} else {
  console.log("No user is signed in.");
  let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProfilePage);
  profileModal.present();
}

console.log("test pause.")
```

While the modal is still being presented and before it is dismissed, "test pause." is being written to the console.  I need it to NOT be written to the console until AFTER the modal is dismissed.

NOTE: I have everything working properly except this bit. I haven't figured out how to accomplish 'pausing' until the modal is dismissed.

Is there any way to do this?

---

### Clarification:

I am presenting the modal in the `ngOnInit()` of the main app component.  I am doing this because I need specific user information to be gathered before the main app component is loaded and any pages are set/added to the stack.

Otherwise, the rootpage will not be built properly.

Here is the updated code in its full context in the `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingsService } from './../services/settings';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from './../pages/home/home';
import { SignInPage } from './../pages/signin/signin';
import { CreatePage } from './../pages/create/create';
import { ProfilePage } from './../modals/profile/profile';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  homePage: any = HomePage;
  signInPage: any = SignInPage;
  createPage: any = CreatePage;
  photoURL: string;

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private platform: Platform, 
              private statusBar: StatusBar, 
              private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDmTh_LZuMPnn7nJRquoW5xWwgQ4Ia3J9E",
      authDomain: "thevault-ba308.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://thevault-ba308.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "thevault-ba308",
      storageBucket: "thevault-ba308.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1024205108979"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      console.log("User is already signed in.");
    } 
    else {
      console.log("No user is signed in.");
      let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProfilePage);
      profileModal.present();
      profileModal.onDidDismiss(() => {
        console.log("test pause.")
        this.photoURL = this.settingsService.getUserPhoto();
        console.log(this.settingsService.getUserName());
      })
    }
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page);
  }

  signOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then((result) => {
      console.log("Sign out success.");
      this.nav.setRoot(SignInPage);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by using [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) in the `app.html` file.

```
<ion-content *ngIf="photoURL != null">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move all the code that was supposed to execute after modal is dismissed in this `modal.onDismiss()` part. Like this:

```
let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProfilePage);
profileModal.present();
profileModal.onDismiss((data) => {
    console.log("Data from modalPage :",data);
    console.log("test pause."); // Here you go. The code will be paused till the modal is dismissed.
});
```

Moreover, you can pass data to the modalPage via `navParams` and retrieve from the modalPage as well using `this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);`.

For more reference, look at [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) and [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals) ionic 2 documentation.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to be more specific. 

I am presenting the modal in the ngOnInit() of the main app component. The reason why is because I need specific user information before the main component is loaded. Unfortunately, your answer does not pause the loading of the main component before the login process completes and the modal is dismissed. It just executes certain commands when the modal is dismissed -- which is not the same.

Therefore, the data I need gets processed too late.

Comment: 1. If it is your main app component, you do not need a modal. Instead, you can set that page via `this.rootPage = ProfilePage` in constructor. 2. Does not matter if it is a main app component, all the code which needs to be followed after modal dismiss can go here. For this may be in the constructor you call modal page at the start and everything rest is followed in `onDismiss()` part. I think some flow of your code is getting executed from another flow like from constructor.